# Use jquery to keep adding numbers to a variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know how to keep adding number to a varible. For instance the number starts at 0 then every time you click the button it adds 20. So the first click would change the variable to 20 then the next click 40. This is as far as I can get..

```
var n = 0;
$('#button).live('click', function() {
    newval = n+20;
    $('.number').append($('<p/>', {text: newval}));     
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` never changes.
You need to replace your `newVal` variable with `n`.

Also, you missed a quote in your selector.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding 20, but not storing the result, here's what you're after:

```
var n = 0;
$('#button').live('click', function() {
    $('.number').append($('<p/>', {text: n += 20}));     
});​
```

[You can see a demo of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/SXF8H/), using `+=` you're adding `20` to `n`, and saving the result back to `n`, previously you were getting but never setting `n`, it was only setting `newVal`, which was thrown away.

Comment: Don't confuse him with side-effects.

Comment: @SLaks: Elaborate?  It simplifies the example, not sure where the confusion would be.